# Help about one math problem -Euclid and copies

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, logic

I' m doing some interesting logical games from time to time, so i've got stuck at some problem, and i am very curious about the solution (i am doing this on some site that edit the solution few days after your answering) so i want to hear your oppinion.
This is the problem: One day, Euclid went to Alexandria. He was called by steward Zenodot. He told him that every copy from their transcripting school is identical, perfect. But, they all are marked with first letter of transcripter name(initial)by its transcripter, and there is no confusion, because every transcripter's name starts with different letter( there is no two person with the same first initial) and he said that Euclid should be honored because king personely demanded that every transcripter make copy of his Elements(king was fan of Euclid). While Zenodot was speaking, Euclid quickly counted copies and said that he was wrong--one transcripter, at least, made two copies. Question is: what's the number of copies Euclid counted?

Answer (score 0):

At least one more than the number of letters in the alphabet they were using.  That sets an upper bound one the number of tanscripters.  It could be any higher number.

Comment: Well, i think the same, but i am confused with that part-'at least' . I have offered answers - a)2 b)8 c)24 d)25 e)48. Greek alphabet has 24 symbols.

Comment: Clearly the intended answer is $25$.  If there were $48$ copies there would be more than one from at least one transcripter.  Either the question should ask for the minimum number of transcripers that make this true or you are supposed to assume that he wouldn't need to count the copies or he would say something different if there were that many duplicates.

Comment: @NenadPantelicSI the "at least" part just means assuming there isn't another mistake, e.g. that one of the transcripters didn't make a copy, which could make room for *two* transcripters to make two copies.